# Does catch streaks increase the odds of finding a shiny in Pokémon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I can’t find a clear answer to whether catch streaks increase or do nothing to the odds of finding a shiny

Comment: Hi Xqc, by 'Catch Streak' do you mean a) The 7 day 'daily catch' streak b) catching lots of Pokemon without having any run away or c) Catching the same type of Pokemon (such as Magikarp) over and over with no other Pokemon between?

Comment: It doesn't. You should read this previous question on Arqade asked for the factors that increase the odds of finding shiny Pokemon and its answer (coincdentally by me): https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/346308/what-affects-the-chances-of-a-shiny-pokemon-encounter/346311#346311. Catch streaks don't increase the odds. They do in Pokemon Let's Go though